# Color data is no being stored properly

Tags: java, rendering, bufferedimage

I am attempting to make a rendering system with a depth map involved with the usual pixels for dealing with alpha. My problem is that no color is being set correctly! I have tried to debug using System.out.println and testing various components, but to no avail I have not found a solution.

**The Variables**
The variables that are involved with dealing with drawing, setting, and clearing of pixels are: `private int[][] node`, `private int[] pixels`, and `private ArrayList<Integer> changedPixels`.

`private int[][] node` deals with storing pixels and dealing with depth [depth][x + y * width] before transferring over to the BufferedImage pixels. The data is set to a clear black and the lowest depth it is a fully visible black.

`private int[] pixels` is the data from a BufferedImage to change it up, it is the only image every used! All data is by default fully visible black

`private ArrayList<Integer> changedPixels` deals with pixels that are there from the last frame so as to help boost FPS by not clearing the entire screen if not needed. Empty by default since not pixels were changed from a previous frame.

**The Methods**
I have several methods for the rendering system: `setNode(int x, int y, int z, int color, int alpha`, `drawScreen()`, and `clearScreen()`. I also have a drawing rectangle and sprite function which deals with adding pixels by calling the `setNode()` method to add in colors.

```
private void setNode(int x, int y, int z, int color, float alpha)
{
    color = Pixel.getColor(alpha, color);

    if (translate) // Move the pixel to  the correct location
    {
        x -= transX;
        y -= transY;
    }

    if (x < 0 || x >= width || y < 0 || y >= height || alpha <= 0.0f || nodeMap[z][x + y * width] == color) // Check if we need to draw the pixel
        return;

    for (int zz = z + 1; zz < maxDepth; zz++)
        if (Pixel.getAlpha(nodeMap[zz][x + y * width]) >= 1)
            return;

    if (alpha < 1.0f) // If pixel isn't completely opaque, then set it's alpha to the given one
        if (nodeMap[z][x + y * width] != color) // If color isn't equal to the one we supply, change it up correctly
            color = Pixel.getColorBlend(color, nodeMap[z][x + y * width]);

    if (color == Pixel.WHITE) System.out.println("Pixel is white at x: " + x + ", y: " + y);
    nodeMap[z][x + y * width] = color;
}

public void drawScreen()
{
    int color = clearColor;

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int z = maxDepth - 1; z > 0; z--)
            {
                if (Pixel.getAlpha(nodeMap[z][x + y * width]) > 0f)
                    color = Pixel.getColorBlend(color, nodeMap[z][x + y * width]);

                if (Pixel.getAlpha(color) >= 1f)
                    break;
            }

            if (pixels[x + y * width] != color)
            {
                pixels[x + y * width] = color;
                changedPixels.add(x + y * width);
            }
        }
}


public void clearScreen()
{
    for (Integer pixel : changedPixels)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < maxDepth; z++)
        {
            if (z > 0)
                nodeMap[z][pixel] = clearColor;
            else
                nodeMap[z][pixel] = bgColor;
        }
    }

    changedPixels.clear();
}

public void drawRect(int offX, int offY, int z, int width, int height, int color)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            setNode(x + offX, y + offY, z, color);
}

public static int getColorBlend(int color1, int color2)
{
    float a1 = getAlpha(color1);
    float a2 = getAlpha(color2);

    float a = Math.max(a1, a2);
    float r = ((getRed(color1) * a1) + (getRed(color2) * a2 * (1 - a1))) / a;
    float g = ((getGreen(color1) * a1) + (getGreen(color2) * a2 * (1 - a1))) / a;
    float b = ((getBlue(color1) * a1) + (getBlue(color2) * a2 * (1 - a1))) / a;

    return Pixel.getColor(a, r, g, b);
}
```

**The Test**
What I do currently is initalize the rendering system and set the nodeMap and pixel map to the previously mentioned settings. After this has been completed a game engine begins and then a method in a gui button (you might need it), but it calls `drawRect(0(x), 0(y), 1(z), 100(width), 20(height), Pixel.WHITE(color))` which works as I have testing to see if it's running the method and which pixels it's drawing to.

**The Problem**
The overall problem is that the screen is completely white, I can't quite figure out the reason! I do know it has nothing with the alpha blending, which works fine as I have used it will a previous version of a rendering system I did.

Any help is appreciate and sorry that this is quite a long question, I just wanted to make sure you had everything you may need help me solve this. I do realize this is not be very effiecent, but I still like the system. Thanks again!

Comment: The main problem was fixed, but now it appears as though a new one has arised, the pixels seem to be retaining previous colors, even though they shouldn't be. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you think the solution is useful to others, please post an answer to your own question. And ask a new one, for the new problem. If not, edit the question to focus on what is the problem now. :-)